# .vbs to sort a list of users favourites

Tags: vbscript

Overall Goal of this script:
To send out to employees and add a set of favourites(web folders) to each laptop. So far I have written(sourced and adapted) a script to add all the folder to the favourites but they are being instered at the end on the favourites list.

I am looking for a way to sort the list of favourites by date or even better to insert the folder at the top of the list so it wont change the order of the current users favourites.

This is what I have so far, the links wont work since they are on our intranet

```
'Create Network Folder*******************************************  


Option Explicit  
MsgBox("Click OK to begin installing all of the Web Folders under My Network Places.")


Sub CreateNetworkFolder(siteURL, siteName)  

Dim iRes, jRes, MT, TT  
Dim SH, newPath  
Dim objFso, f, fs, g  

Dim bString  
Dim ltrIndex  
Dim nameLength, urlLength, urlCutoff  
Dim aFile  
Dim filesys

'ForWriting (2) is the attribute to be set when writing to a file.  
Const ForWriting = 2  

nameLength = Len(siteName)  
urlLength = Len(siteURL)  
'44 seems to be the length where we have to change a 00 to a 01.  
urlCutoff = 44  

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

Set SH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  

'Create the folder under Favorites that will hold the target.lnk file  
newPath = SH.SpecialFolders("Favorites") & "\" & "BCKM" & "\"  

'Creating the housing folder for BCKM
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If filesys.FolderExists(newPath) Then
   'msgbox "File esists"
  else
   'msgbox "file does not exist"
   objFso.CreateFolder(newPath) 
End If



'Create the webfolder for each section
newPath = SH.SpecialFolders("Favorites") & "\" & "BCKM" & "\" & siteName 
objFso.CreateFolder(newPath) 

'We ceate a Desktop.ini file  
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
aFile = newPath & "\Desktop.ini"  

Set f = fs.OpenTextFile( aFile, ForWriting, True )  

'Write the data lines that will make this a folder shortcut.  
f.WriteLine "[.ShellClassInfo]"  
f.WriteLine "CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}"  
f.WriteLine "Flags=2"  
f.WriteLine "ConfirmFileOp=0" 



f.Close  

'We make Desktop.ini a system-hidden file by assigning it attribute of 6  
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set g = fs.GetFile(newPath & "\Desktop.ini")  
g.Attributes = 6  

'We make the folder read-only by assigning it 1.  
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set g = fs.GetFolder(newPath)  
g.Attributes = 1  

'This is where we construct the target.lnk file byte by byte. Most of  
'the lines are shown in 16 byte chunks,  
'mostly because that is the way I saw it in the Debug utility I was  
'using to inspect shortcut files.  

'Line 1, 16 bytes  
bString = Chr(&H4C) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H01) & Chr(&H14) & Chr(&H02) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&HC0) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'Line 2, 16 bytes  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H46) & Chr(&H81) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'Line 3, 16 bytes  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'Line 4., 16 bytes. 13th byte is significant.  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H01) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'Line 5. 13th byte is significant.  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'When I was analyzing the next byte of shortcuts I created, I found  
'that it is set to various values,  
'and I have no idea what they are referring to. In desperation I tried  
'substituting some values.  
'00 caused a crash of Explorer. FF seeems to work fine for all.  
'If anyone can get back to me on what this byte is or why FF works,  
'please contact me.  
bString = bString & Chr(&HFF)  

'This byte is 00 if the URL is 44 characters or less, 01 if greater.  
If urlLength > urlCutoff Then  
bString = bString & Chr(&H01)  
Else  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00)  
End If  

bString = bString & Chr(&H14) & Chr(&H00)  

'Line 6, 16 bytes  
bString = bString & Chr(&H1F) & Chr(&H50) & Chr(&HE0) & Chr(&H4F) & Chr(&HD0) & Chr(&H20) & Chr(&HEA) & Chr(&H3A) & Chr(&H69) & Chr(&H10) & Chr(&HA2) & Chr(&HD8) & Chr(&H08) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H2B) & Chr(&H30)  

'Line 7, 16 bytes  
bString = bString & Chr(&H30) & Chr(&H9D) & Chr(&H14) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H2E) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&HDF) & Chr(&HEA) & Chr(&HBD) & Chr(&H65) & Chr(&HC2) & Chr(&HD0) & Chr(&H11) & Chr(&HBC) & Chr(&HED)  

'Line 8, 16 bytes  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&HA0) & Chr(&HC9) & Chr(&H0A) & Chr(&HB5) & Chr(&H0F) & Chr(&HA4)  

'This byte is 00 if the URL is 44 characters or less, 01 if greater.  
If urlLength > urlCutoff Then  
bString = bString & Chr(&H01)  
Else  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00)  
End If  

bString = bString & Chr(&H4C) & Chr(&H50) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H01) & Chr(&H42) & Chr(&H57) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'Line 9, 16 bytes  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H10) & Chr(&H00)  

'Line 10, 2 bytes  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'The next byte represents the length of the site name.  
bString = bString & Chr(nameLength)  

'Take the site name, and write each letter, preceeded by a "00"  
'character.  

For ltrIndex = 1 to nameLength  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Mid(siteName, ltrIndex, 1)  
Next  

'Middle line, separates the Folder Name from the URL. 3 bytes.  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'The next byte represents the length of the site URL.  
bString = bString & Chr(urlLength)  

'Take the site URL, and write each letter, preceeded by a "00"  
'character.  
For ltrIndex = 1 to urlLength  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Mid(siteURL, ltrIndex, 1)  
Next  

'Last line, 13 bytes  
bString = bString & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00) & Chr(&H00)  

'Let's create the target.lnk file.  
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
aFile = newPath & "\target.lnk"  
'aFile = newPath & "\vb.sss"  
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(aFile, ForWriting, True)  
f.Write bString  
f.Close  

End Sub  

'This is where you specify the folders to add

CreateNetworkFolder "http://collaboration.au.xxx.com/dav/1.11.685732/", "Clients" 
CreateNetworkFolder "http://collaboration.au.xxx.com/dav/1.11.685930/", "Workspaces" 
CreateNetworkFolder "http://collaboration.au.xxx.com/dav/1.11.685941/", "Practice Management" 
CreateNetworkFolder "http://collaboration.au.xxx.com/dav/1.11.685945/", "Tips" 
CreateNetworkFolder "http://collaboration.au.xxx.com/dav/1.21.8015/", "Discussion Board" 


MsgBox("All Web Folders Added Succesfully. Please check Favorites to Confirm. Press OK")
```

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on Helen's answer, the "undocumented data" in the registry key are a binary form of the relative PCUITEMID_CHILD (See MSDN) - relative to the folder where the .lnk files are stored on disk. This requires using a language that can access COM interfaces, such as C++.

The registry key has the header as documented in the article - however, the records are simply the length of record (DWORD), the 'order' value (DWORD) and the PCUITEMID_CHILD data.

```
typedef struct _FAV_ORDERED_HEADER_
{
    DWORD dwFormatValue;    // Typically 8 for known Windows versions that use this
    DWORD dwSubFormatValue; // Typically 2 for known Windows that use this
    DWORD dwTotalDataLen;   // Total bytes in all data
    DWORD dwReserved;       // No known use
    DWORD dwNumRecords;     // Number of records
} FAV_ORDERED_HEADER;

typedef struct _FAV_ORDERED_RECORD_
{
    DWORD dwLenRecord;       // Length of each record (skip this bytes to get next record)
    DWORD dwOrderValue;      // Negative if not ordered (add to end), positive if on list first
    ITEMIDLIST pidlLinkData; // PIDL data for the individiual link - need to use a PIDL compare to be able to compare to actual .lnk file links.
} FAV_ORDERED_RECORD;
```

1. First use SHGetFolderLocation(NULL,CSIDL_FAVORITES,NULL,NULL,&ppidlFavorites) to get the PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE of the Favorites folder.
2. Get the desktop IShellFolder interface pointer via SHGetDesktopFolder()
3. Use the IShellFolder instance to get to the Favorites IShellFolder via IShellFolder::BindToObject(ppidlFavorites,NULL, IID_IShellFolder, &pFavoritesShellFolder)
4. Use the pFavoritesShellFolder with calls to IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf() with the data into the pidl parameter - and set the SHGDNF parameters for the string(s) to get - the display name, URL, etc. are typically obtained through this method.

This applies to the Windows 7/8 'Favorites' in the shell links. However, it requires the use of the IKnownFolderManager::GetFolder(FOLDERID_Links,&pLinksKnFolder) to get the IKnownFolder that will allow the eventual retrieval of the required IShellFolder - to properly get it's PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE. It's registry key (for link ordering) is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\CommonPlaces
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you create shortcuts in such a bizarre way? This can be done a lot easier by calling [`WshShell.CreateShortcut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys.aspx) and setting the properties of the resulting [`WshShortcut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5y78918.aspx) object.

Now to your sorting question. There're two registry keys that manage the state of Favorites:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MenuOrder\Favorites` — corresponds to favorites displayed in Internet Explorer.
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MenuOrder\Favorites` — corresponds to favorites displayed in Windows Start menu > Favorites.

The sort order of favorites is stored in the DWORD `Order` value of these keys. For each folder in Favorites there's the corresponding subkey that also has the `Order` value. The internal structure of the `Order` value is undocumented, but [this article](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/iefavorites.html) provides some analysis and explanation.

So, to change the sort order you could try modifying this value from your script, for example, using the WMI [`StdRegProv.GetDWORDValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390445.aspx) and [`StdRegProv.SetDWORDValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393297.aspx) methods. However, I guess it'd be rather tricky.

Note that deleting these abovementioned keys from the registry should [sort Favorites in alphabetical order](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177482), if that's an option.